# After I used onTouchlistener then onclick listener stops working in recyclerview

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am using dragging feature for recycler view by using ItemTouch helper. 
Dragging is working fine but I am unable to use onclick listener on the same view.

Below is my code:

```
  holder.mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mCommunicator.onStartDrag(holder);
            return false;
        }
    });

    holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //LogManager.v(LOG_TAG,"touch:"+blnOnTouch);
            holder.checkBox.performClick();

             });
```

Please suggest me for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: not an error , on click event is not triggering thats my issue

Comment: `holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.checkBox.performClick();
            }
        });`

Comment: tried this , but not working

Comment: `mainLayout` is linearlayout?

Comment: No its Relative layout

Comment: add `android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"`

Comment: yes tried but same output, its going to ontouchlistener method